# Input value to an Excel file

Tags: excel, autoit

I wrote an AutoIt script to get an input value and save that in an Excel file:

```
#include <Excel.au3>
#include <Array.au3>

Local $oExcel = _Excel_Open()
Local $oWorkbook = _Excel_BookNew($oExcel)
Local $aArray1D[1] = ["1"]

_Excel_RangeWrite($oWorkbook, $oWorkbook.Activesheet, $aArray1D, "A1")
_Excel_BookSaveAs($oWorkbook, "C:\Desktop\Data.xls")
_Excel_BookClose($oWorkbook)
```

But I get the below error on compiling:

```
_Excel_Open() : undefined function
```

and the same for `_Excel_BookNew()`, `_Excel_RangeWrite()`, `_Excel_BookSaveAs()` and `_Excel_BookClose()`. I'm not able to rectify it.

Comment: I suspect that you are using an older version of autoit that does not support these functions. According to the change log the excel UDF was rewritten in v3.3.12.0. Please refer to the help file that came with the version that you have installed or update to the latest version of autoit.

Answer (score 0):

In this case `undefined function` indicates that something is wrong with your UDF file.

Check if you have an Excel.au3 file in your include folder and that it contains a function called `_Excel_Open()`. If that is not the case you most likely are *not using the latest version of AutoIt*, either update it or try to find the Excel UDF online.

However, if the file contains the named functions, try copying the file into your script directory to test if somehow the path to your include file got messed up.

Answer (score -2):

Add this to the head of your code:

```
#include <FileConstants.au3>
```